# How do I get a list of the categories column, and then list of everything in a single view?

Tags: django

I want a navbar on top of my page with the categories in my model.
And when I click on the link to a category, I want a table that lists the items in that category.

For whatever reason I just can't get both things to work at the same time.

This is my model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class menulist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=10, default=100.00)
    category_choices = (
        ('breads', 'Breads'),
        ('cakes', 'Cakes'),
        ('hotfood', 'Hot Food'),
        ('porkrolls', 'Pork Rolls'),
        ('drinks', 'Drinks'),
        ('MISC', 'Misc'),
    )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=category_choices, default='MISC',)
    dateadded = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    dateupdated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', default='products/blank.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is the view:

```
class ProductAdminView(ListView):
    template_name = 'menulistapp/product_admin.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductAdminView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        categorylist = menulist._meta.get_field('category').choices
        context = {
            "category_list": categorylist,
        }
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs.get("slug")
        if slug:
            queryset = menulist.objects.filter(category__iexact=slug)
        else:
            queryset = menulist.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

html template:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    <div class="container ">

        <ul class="nav nav-pills border-bottom border-top pt-2 pb-2">
            {% for a, b in category_list %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/productadmin/{{ a }}">{{ b }}</a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

</div>


    <!-- tables -->

      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

              <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
                  <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 15%"scope="col"></th>
                        <th style="width: 55%" scope="col">Product Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Category</th>
                        <th scope="col">Price</th>
                        <th scope="col">Date Added</th>
                        <th scope="col">Last Updated</th>

                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {% for obj in object_list %}

                    <tr>
                        <td class="align-middle"><img src="{{ obj.img.url }}" class="img-fluid"></td>
                        <td class="align-middle">{{ obj }}</td>
                        <td class="align-middle">{{ obj.category }}</td>
                        <td class="align-middle">${{ obj.price }}</td>
                        <td class="align-middle">{{ obj.dateadded }}</td>
                        <td class="align-middle">{{ obj.dateupdated }}</td>

                    </tr>

                    {% endfor %}

                  </tbody>
                </table>

          </div>
      </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Sometimes I can only get the list working if I comment out the nav bar, and vice versa.

I've looked at mixins, but that only confused me more and doesn't do anything.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code the definition of `cat`. Are you sure that your url rightly points to the view `ProductAdminView` ?

Comment: Sorry, I spent 3 hours yesterday editing the code trying to figure out why it wasn't working, my head was thumping. So it was a jumbled mess. I have fixed the navbar issue. But I still can't load the main table unless I comment out the navbar.